# TensorFlow low GPU utilization

Tags: gpu

I am running Windows 10 on a Core I7-8700 CPU with a GeForce GTX 1660 Ti. When training models, the GPU utilization is very low (5-10% at max, sometimes lower) even if the network is five layers. CPU utilization on the other hand is 30% and above.
How can I increase GPU utilization to 100% or near it?